# Can a creature with megamorph block then morph?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

Imagine I have a 2/2 creature that can be megamorphed, can I block with it and pay its megamorph cost before damages are done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can. Morph/megamorph can be used any time you have priority. After declaring blockers but before combat damage is assigned and dealt, there will be a priority pass where you can megamorph your creature.

> **702.36e:** **Any time you have priority**, you may turn a face-down permanent you control with a morph ability face up. This is a special action; it doesn't use the stack...

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that trickery like this was a major part of morph deck tournament deck strategies. :)

Comment: Hehe is that so @doppelgreener? I wasn't around when morph originally appeared, but I remember the more recent formats only had a few playable morphs; you could usually tell which ones they were without them flipping up.

In more casual play of course, the shell game that is morph creatures is very fun!

Comment: In the Khans of Tarkir standard pro tours, one of the recurring top-ranked decks was Temur Morph: it played 1-ofs and 2-ofs of 20-30 different equally great morph and megamorph cards, so you never had any clue what any single card was. Opponents couldn't guess what to block or what to remove.

Comment: If it doesn't use the stack, I suppose there can't be an answer to this action an that it can't be countered, even by Disallow?

Comment: Yes, Morph does not use the stack so you cannot respond to it. In fact, you can even Morph in response to a spell with Split Second, one of the few things you CAN do in response to that. However, while Disallow cannot counter the flip, it can still counter any triggered abilities that trigger when the card flips over.